# create smtp authentication route with haproxy

Tags: java, authentication, smtp, haproxy

Is it possible to insert username and authentication password in the haproxy route towards an smtp with authentication?

now I have a route like:

frontend SMTP
bind *:25
mode tcp
default_backend smtp
backend smtp
balance roundrobin
mode tcp
server vm3 smtp.domain.global:25 check

calling the route with a java job:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.3 Client was not authenticated

it is difficult for me to modify the java job now, while I would like to modify the haproxy configuration

Comment: So, you are exposing username/password on haproxy, and any one that call the endpoint can send emails on behalf of that user?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hi pringi,  correct, for now mine is only a feasibility analysis of the problem. I have to understand if it is possible or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the pasted config looks a little bit odd let me format it.

```
frontend SMTP
  bind *:25
  mode tcp
  default_backend smtp

backend smtp 
  balance roundrobin
  mode tcp
  server vm3 smtp.domain.global:25 check
```

Hope this makes now clear why it's not possible.
HAProxy does not handle the SMTP Protocol, it just forwards the connection via TCP to the mail server therefore can't the SMTP Auth be injected nor done by HAProxy.